# Make thread to return value in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have web service and web service calls are handled by a Thread, so that they can run asynchronously, and also time out.  But the thread is “runnable” and not “callable” so the thread cannot pass back the web service response.

I have read statement that we need to use a callable.Is their any way to return response from my runnable thread.I am posting small example can we make it to return value.

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
        String a="Hello";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new HelloThread()).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: As thread runs asynchronously, there is no chance for returning value from one thread to another thread. So, if they are in once class you can think of taking one global variable but that is also not effective for some situation as threads run parallelly.

Comment: You should take a look at the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface

Answer (score 4):

You should pass a callback to the `Thread` and the thread can invoke the callback with the value when its done.

Comment: how to pass a callback to thread

Comment: Pass the callback as a object within the constructor of the thread  and store it as a instance variable of your thread instance (of course you have to implement the constructor in your thread implementation).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an explicit thread, you can make use of the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface.

You can instantiate it using the `Executors` class, and then call `submit` and pass a `Callable` to it. This will start running the code in `Callable` in a different thread, and immediately return to you a `Future` object.

You can then call `get` on the `Future` in order to wait for the asynchronous execution of the `Callable` to finish, and to retrieve its result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return values from threads. But you may be interested in looking and using the `SwingWorker`. It enables you to run some work in background and can return something when it has completed using its `done` and `get` methods.

[Here it is in more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Another way is to define a variable before the thread starts running and assign some value to it inside the `run` method of the thread. This way you will be able to use that variable when the thread has finished. **But** again you have to deal with all those `concurrency`,  and `locks` and other stuff.